# How to make webglcandlestick series respect the bandwidth function?

Tags: d3.js, d3fc

I am following this example from the d3fc github repo: https://github.com/d3fc/d3fc/blob/master/examples/series-webgl-candlestick/index.js

My understanding is that the default bandwidth is 5px and the example above is not over-riding that setting.

If I change the relevant part of the code above to:

```
const series = fc
    .seriesWebglCandlestick()
    .bandwidth(100)
    .xScale(xScale)
    .yScale(yScale)
    .defined(() => true)
    .equals(d => d.length)
    ;
```

That should space the candles at 100px each. Instead my display shows the image below:

[image]

Which doesn't look like it's being spaced correctly.

Edit:

Following the suggestion below, I tried modifying this provided Codepen (https://codepen.io/colineberhardt-the-bashful/pen/VwvzYmP?editors=1111) to use 100px candles and on my screen it is still displaying incorrectly:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know that an 'it works for me' answer isn't ideal, however, this simple example does show bandwidth working as expected ...

```
const data = fc.randomFinancial()(50);

const container = document.querySelector('canvas');
container.width= 300;
container.height= 300;

const xScale = d3
    .scaleTime()
    .range([0, 300])
    .domain(fc.extentDate().accessors([d => d.date])(data));

const yScale = d3
    .scaleLinear()
    .range([300, 0])
    .domain(fc.extentLinear().accessors([d => d.high])(data));

const series = fc
    .seriesWebglCandlestick()
    // .bandwidth(100)
    .xScale(xScale)
    .yScale(yScale)
    .context(container.getContext('webgl'));

series(data);
```

See the following codepen: https://codepen.io/colineberhardt-the-bashful/pen/VwvzYmP?editors=1111

removing the comment that sets the bandwidth to 100 causes each candlestick to be 100px wide.

Comment: This must be a bug in the charting library. If I just remove the comment in that codepen on my computer the chart displays incorrectly. I've attached a screenshot to my original answer to illustrate.